# Flutter: Couldn't reach the class properties in Build Widget with Firebase connection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Everytime when I try to use loggegInUser property it returns null please help me to solve this issue
getCurrent() methods works properly and prints user email and password but I can not acces this variables in Build Widget.

```
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
      final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
      String uid;
      var url;
      var userProfilePhotoUrl;
    
      int currentPageIndex = 2;
      CircularBottomNavigationController _navigationController =
          new CircularBottomNavigationController(2);
    
      List<TabItem> tabItems = List.of([
        new TabItem(Icons.home, "Home", Colors.blue,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
        new TabItem(Icons.add, "Let's Party", Colors.orange,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        new TabItem(Icons.person, "Reports", Colors.red),
      ]);
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getCurrentUser();
      }
    
      void getCurrentUser() async {
        try {
          final user = await _auth.currentUser();
          if (user != null) {
            loggedInUser = user;
            uid = user.uid;
            print(loggedInUser.email);
            print(uid);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      void changePage(int index) {
        setState(() {
          currentPageIndex = index;
        });
      }
    
      Future<FirebaseImage> getFirebaseProfilPhoto() async {
        try {
          final user = await _auth.currentUser();
          if (user != null) {
            loggedInUser = user;
            uid = user.uid;
            print(loggedInUser.email);
            print(uid);
            return FirebaseImage(
                'gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        setState(() {
          getCurrentUser();
        });
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('furkanakguun'),
          ),
          body: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                        backgroundImage: FirebaseImage(
                            'gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png'),
                        // FirebaseImage(
                        //     'gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/$uid.png'),
                        //backgroundImage: Image.network(userProfilePhotoUrl),
                        radius: 100,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                            size: 30.0,
                          ),
                          focusColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Colors.deepPurple,
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('asd');
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'image_uploader');
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.person),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 7.0),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text('Furkan Akgün',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 7.0),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text('Ankara',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.rate_review),
                      ),
                      Card(
                        color: Colors.grey[900],
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 7.0),
                        child: Container(
                            child: SmoothStarRating(
                          spacing: 2.0,
                          allowHalfRating: true,
                          starCount: 5,
                          rating: 4.5,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          borderColor: Colors.white,
                          isReadOnly: true,
                        )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple[900],
                        onPressed: () {
                          //uploadPic(context);
                        },
                        elevation: 4.0,
                        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: Text(
                          'Edit',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: CircularBottomNavigation(
            tabItems,
            barBackgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            controller: _navigationController,
            selectedCallback: (int selectedPos) {
              if (selectedPos == 0) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'dashboard_screen');
              }
              if (selectedPos == 2) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'user_profile');
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wg12.png)

ERROR TYPE
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid)

Comment: at which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: return FirebaseImage(
                'gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png');
          } In this line when I rty to reach loggedInUser.uid it returns null

Comment: But loggedInUser.email is printing the email??

Comment: Yes it prints. getCurrentUser() method works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the error comes from this code in your `build` method:

```
FirebaseImage('gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png')
```

This is because the UI may be built before the user sign-in is completed.

To prevent this from happening you need to handle the fact that the user may not be signed in, in your `build` code too, for example by skipping the rendering of their profile image:

```
backgroundImage: loggedInUser != null ? 
                    FirebaseImage('gs://homeparty-68792.appspot.com/user_profile_images/${loggedInUser.uid}.png') : 
                    Text("Loading...")
```

Comment: I wrote your code I don't get any  errors  but the user photos never load.

Comment: That's a different problem. I'm not sure what `FirebaseImage` does, and if it can handle `gs://` URLs. I'd recommend posting a new question for that part, as the same problem would occur with a non-user-specific image, while the problem I addressed here is that the user state is determined asynchronously.

Comment: Is there any way to load image form firebase with current user uid i think i will post a new question for that.